# The photon clock thought experiment

Tags: photons, thought-experiment, time

In reference to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GguAN1_JouQ&index=4&list=PLsPUh22kYmNDRYfImV3BzNZ6yTwhIpe0k).

If a photon clock moves away from us the photon will travel greater distance and therefore the clock will tick slower, so I would assume it will tick slower if it is moving towards us as well.
So if it goes away from us then back towards us, then we would notice the clock is late.

But in the video they say the person riding with that clock will see our clock as running slower than their.
Does this mean they will see it as running faster when this other clock is moving back towards us?

I'm just trying t understand this thought experiment...

Comment: The world looks exactly the same from the viewpoint of the other observer. He sees your photon clock behave exactly the same as you see his. That's the core observation that gives rise to relativity. Neither of the two observers can tell who is at rest and who is moving because all movement is relative to something else.

Comment: @CuriousOne Does that mean that the clocks will be in sync once the other clock moves back to the starting position (next to our clock) ?

Comment: Watch the video, again, the animation is actually helpful to understand what is happening. Imagine a clock that is in constant relative motion to you. As you have seen, the path length that the photon has to traverse in the clock is longer, from your point of view, than from the observer who travels with the photon. This is independent of whether the clock is moving from the left to the right or the opposite direction. So if you move a clock away from you, it will show less time. Now you turn it around, and it will show less time passing on the way back, again. In total it will show less time.

Comment: @CuriousOne So that would mean that this other person will see our clock as moving faster then theirs on their way back and will on the end see that our clock is ahead of theirs, right?

Comment: You are confusing the relative flow of time with what a moving observer "sees" when they are moving away from you and towards you, which is further modified by the Doppler effect. That is what you are thinking about: redshift when something is moving away, blue-shift when something is moving closer. That is not what relativity calls "time dilation". Time dilation is independent of the direction of the movement. Doppler shift is dependent on the direction.

Comment: @CuriousOne You are right, I did confuse the two. Anyway I think I got it now. Thanks for helping :)